# ObservableCollection has Depedency Property in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Recently i was developing a custom control in Silverlight, I created custom dependency property which is of type ObservableCollection. I have another 2 custom dependency properties of type strings. My requirement is on addition of any item to collection, I have to fire collectionChanged Event , in this event handler, i want to update the other 2 dependency properties.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty itemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<ValidationErrorMessage>), typeof(SummaryUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<ValidationErrorMessage>(), new PropertyChangedCallback(fun1)));
    public ObservableCollection<ValidationErrorMessage> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<ValidationErrorMessage>)base.GetValue(itemsProperty);
        }
        set
        {

            base.SetValue(itemsProperty, value);
        }
    }


public static void fun1(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs       evt)
    {
        var newValue =   evt.NewValue as ObservableCollection<ValidationErrorMessage>;

        if(newValue!=null)
            newValue.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(CollectionChangedHandler);

        var oldValue  = evt.OldValue as ObservableCollection<ValidationErrorMessage>;
        if(oldValue!=null)
            oldValue.CollectionChanged -= new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(CollectionChangedHandler);
    }

    static void CollectionChangedHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
           var newItems =     e.NewItems as ObservableCollection<ValidationErrorMessage>;
           foreach (var item in newItems)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    static void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }



public static readonly DependencyProperty headerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(String), typeof(SummaryUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty, null));
    public String Header
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)base.GetValue(headerProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(headerProperty, value);
            RaisePropertyChange("Header");
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty messageTypeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MessageType", typeof(MessageEnumType), typeof(SummaryUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(MessageEnumType.Error, null));
    public MessageEnumType MessageType
    {
        get { return (MessageEnumType)GetValue(messageTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(messageTypeProperty, value); RaisePropertyChange("MessageType"); }
    }
```

How can I change the values of the dependency properties messageType and Header? I'm unable to access those properties in either the `CollectionChanged` or `NotifyPropertyChanged` event since all those events are static. I cannot access the instance within these static event handlers.

I tried to fix the problem with a converter, but my curosity on Silverlight makes me want to use the above approach. How can I set values for those dependency properties within `CollectionChanged` event or `NotifyPropertyChanged` events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *sender* in your static *fun1* method should be the instance of the class which declares the itemsProperty DependencyProperty. Therefore you can access the concrete instance with casting the sender to your class.

```
public static void fun1(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs       evt) 
{
     MyClass concreteInstance = sender as MyClass;
     if(concreateInstance != null)
     {
         [...your code...]
     }
}
```